# SSH tunnel to VM created on Google Cloud Platform doesn't work

Tags: python, ssh, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, virtual-machine

I'm trying to connect to a VM create on Google Cloud Platform through a SSH tunnel. The problem is not in the code, since it works for other VM created on different platforms. The problem is that the code I wrote to connect my jupyter notebook to the instance run for many minutes without giving me any error.

Here's my code:
`gcloud compute ssh $NODE --project=$PROJ --zone=$ZONE -- -fN -L $PORT:localhost:$PORT`

the info used into the code (I ran it from jupyter notebook with `%%bash` magic command) are right, I still don't know why the code takes so much time to establish a connection (and It is not able to do it by the way).
Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a compute instance to route all your traffic through it. If you have an existing instance, you can use it, or create a new a compute instance named tunnel from Google Cloud Platform Console or from gcloud:

```
gcloud compute instances create --zone us-west1-a tunnel
```

Start an SSH tunnel on your machine on a local port, such as 5000, that connects to a GCE instance on its SSH port 22:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone us-west1-a tunnel -- -N -p 22 -D localhost:5000
```

This command works out of the box on macOS, Windows and Linux, and starts an SSH tunnel which can be used as a SOCKS proxy. This command will keep running until it is terminated, which will shut down the tunnel. If you do wish to run it in the background, pass an additional -f flag to the command.

Comment: I already created an instance. However, the connection cannot be established because the code run without stopping